# How can I make an element that remains on screen as I slide between pages?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a CarouselPage with 3 pages and I want to make something like a banner at the top of my screen that, as I slide between the pages, stays on the screen. My CarouselPage setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Planetarium_V2.CarouselSystem"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Planetarium_V2">
    <local:GameListPage></local:GameListPage>
    <local:MainHubPage></local:MainHubPage>
    <local:PlaceholderPage></local:PlaceholderPage>
 </CarouselPage>
```

It doesn't seem possible to do it using CarouselPage so I tried making a CarouselView and loading the pages inside but that doesn't really work. How I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Planetarium_V2.Test"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Planetarium_V2.Classes">
   <ContentPage.BindingContext>
       <vm:PopulatePages></vm:PopulatePages>
   </ContentPage.BindingContext>

   <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding pages}">
   </CarouselView>
</ContentPage>
```

PopulatePages code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Planetarium_V2.Classes
{
    class PopulatePages
    {
        public List<ContentPage> pages { get; set; }
        public PopulatePages()
        {
            pages = new List<ContentPage>()
            {
                new GameListPage(),
                new MainHubPage(),
                new PlaceholderPage()

            };
        }
    }
}
```

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7cR7.png)

[What I try to achieve (I hope the professionally made drawing isn't confusing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIkWa.png)

Comment: Put Carousel with banner inside a Grid?

Answer (score 0):

What you mentioned sounds more like the TabbedPage instead of the CarouselPage.
You can create a TabbedPage and set it as the MainPage in the App.xaml.cs.

Here is the code you can refer to:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPageWithNavigationPage;assembly=TabbedPageWithNavigationPage"
            x:Class="TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.MainPage">
    <local:TodayPage />
    <NavigationPage Title="Schedule" IconImageSource="schedule.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:SchedulePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

More information you can check this [Xamarin.Forms TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page).

Comment: So what I want to achieve is a CarouselPage so I can slide between pages and have some graphic stuff overlaying that stays on screen as I change between the pages. I have tried using a TabbedPage but I can't seem to find a way to achieve what I want with it. for now I decided to use a NavigationPage with a CarouselPage inside and just modify the Navigation Tab. Edit: Note that I do NOT need the navigation Tab but I can change it to look however I like so I could use it for my specific use-case.